# How to update Laravel data in real time?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In my laravel project users can like posts, the action is submitted via AJAX so the page does not refresh however I still need to find a way to make the number of likes update.

The form that submits the like command, as well as where the number of likes is displayed:

```
<form action="/heart/{{$post->id}}" id="heartForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<input type="image" href="#" src="/images/heart.png" class="heart link-block-3 w-inline-block"></form>

<div class="text-block-16">{{$post->likers()->count()}}</div>
```

The Controller:

```
public function heart($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $user->toggleLike($post);

    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The AJAX I have so far:

```
<script>
    // this is the id of the form
    $("#heartForm").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success! Logged for testing purposes.')
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

It should probably be noted that I am using the Overtrue/laravel-like plugin to make all this work.

Simply put is there a way to make laravel update the number of likes on my page without the page reloading? I'm assuming this can be done with AJAX but I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: You could maybe also fetch the number of likes with ajax? Then, when someone likes an item refetch the number of likes. You could do this roughly the same way you're ajax request works now but on the success function execute something to change the like number.

Comment: [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting) would be the way to go